# Assigning message to UILabel infinite times

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one SKLableNode and i want to assign it different messages with 10 seconds time interval

```
    NSString *strMessage1=@"Message1";
    NSString *strMessage2=@"Message2";
    NSString *strMessage3=@"Message3";
    NSString *strMessage4=@"Message4";
    NSString *strMessage5=@"Message5";
    NSString *strMessage6=@"Message6";
    NSString *strMessage7=@"Message7";
    NSString *strMessage8=@"Message8";
    NSString *strMessage9=@"Message9";
    NSString *strMessage10=@"Message10";
```

What is the best solution for it. 
Thanks

Comment: Look into `NSTimer`.

Comment: rmaddy is correct. Plus, you could use `SKAction` since you say in your post that you use `SKLabelNode` (even tough your title suggest otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable globaly in .m

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene

SKLabelNode *lblMessage;

NSTimer *timerForMessage;

int i;

NSArray *arrMessageToUser;
```

Now initialise the variable **i** and **arrMessageToUser** in **-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size**

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {             
    i=0;         
    arrMessageToUser=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Message1",@"Message2",@"Message3",@"Message4",@"Message5",@"Message6",@"Message7",@"Message8",@"Message9",@"Message10", nil];

}
}
```

Now on Button tap call the Method **messageToUser** and initialise the time with 10 seconds time interval

```
-(void)buttonClick{  

[self messageToUser];

timerForMessage=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(messageToUser) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Now here assign the message from **arrMessageToUser** to **lblMessage**
-(void)messageToUser{

```
NSString *msg=arrMessageToUser[i];
lblMessage.text=msg;
i++;
if (i==10) {
    i=0;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyClass

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSUInteger numberOfTimerEventsFired;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKLabelNode labelNode;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.f
   target:self
   selector:@selector(updateLabel)
   userInfo:nil 
   repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateLabel
{
    self.numberOfTimerEventsFired++;
    NSUInteger eventsFired = self.numberOfTimerEventsFired;
    self.labelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message%lu", eventsFired];
    if (eventsFired == 10)
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
}

@end
```

Please forgive any typos as this was written from a windows machine but this should give you a rough idea about how to use a NSTimer to schedule a repeating action using target/selector